# Empty WordCloud PNG outputted from Arabic Text

Tags: python-3.x, word-cloud

`

```
import arabic_reshaper
from pyarabic.araby import tokenize
from pyarabic.unshape import unshaping_text
from pyarabic import araby
import matplotlib.pyplot as pPlot
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import numpy as npy
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
text = '⁭الْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ الْعَالَمِينَ  الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيمِ  مَالِكِ يَوْمِ الدِّينِ  إِيَّاكَ نَعْبُدُ وَإِيَّاكَ نَسْتَعِينُ  اهْدِنَا الصِّرَاطَ الْمُسْتَقِيمَ  صِرَاطَ الَّذِينَ أَنْعَمْتَ عَلَيْهِمْ غَيْرِ الْمَغْضُوبِ عَلَيْهِمْ وَلَا الضَّالِّينَ'
text_to_be_reshaped = text
reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(text_to_be_reshaped)
rev_text = reshaped_text[::-1]   
dictionary = {}
lst = tokenize(rev_text)
for elements in lst:  
    if elements in dictionary: 
        dictionary[elements] += 1
    else: 
        dictionary.update({elements: 1})
print(dictionary) # you can delete this print func but just to show you that 
                  # everything is perfect but got empty png :-/
cloud = WordCloud(background_color = "white", max_words = 200)
cloud.generate_from_frequencies(dictionary)
cloud.to_file("wordCloud.png")`
```

[image: My actual output]
The problem is I built successful Python script which iterates through arabic text and count each word frequency but wordcloud is outputting empty PNG like the image above and I couldn't solve it, probably it has to do with utf-8 encoding but I still don't know how to implement it in wordcloud. The text reading, iterating and counting word frequencies code is working flawlessly since it is perfectly iterating and counting words frequencies of any Arabic text which is somehow uncommon, so this is my little kudo to all users. Thank you very much for help.

Comment: It looks like the font that is in use here does not have the required Arabic characters. So select a font that does. I'm actually amazed it did a good job nevertheless – this is not *empty* at all.

Comment: Thanks bro. I solved it. The code is ready for use. Enjoy & share :-)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. It was font_path behind the issue so simply add the font. Now it is Fully Working

```
cloud = WordCloud(background_color = "white", font_path = 'arial.ttf', max_words = 200, stopwords = set(STOPWORDS))
```